# NoSuchMethod error sometimes

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, servlets, web

### Sometimes after deploy of my application on tomcat 8 i get :

```
2017 06 05 10:34:47#+0300#ERROR#org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/]##anonymous#localhost-startStop-1#na###web##StandardWrapper.Throwablejava.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:331)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:390)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:172)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:364)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1099)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:989)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4931)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5241)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1823)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:805)
```

---

I guess sometimes it gets different dependency that doesn`t have the .getProperties() method ,but how i do choose which one to be used everytime

Answer (score 1):

Which version of JAX-RS jar you have in your classpath or your classpath contain both JAX-RS 1(`jsr311-api.jar`) and JAX-RS 2(`javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar`) jar.If in your classpath you have `jsr311-api.jar` which is JAX-RS 1.`jsr311-api.jar` doesn't have the method `getProperties()` hence you are getting `NoSuchMethodError`.Use the `javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar` in your classpath it will fix your problem.

Comment: how can i explicitly tell it to use the javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar  ?

Comment: exclude the dependency of jsr311-api from your pom.xml  and only keep the artifact fact which is related to JAX RS 2

Comment: <dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.1</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
    <exclusions>
     <exclusion>
      <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
     </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
   </dependency>

  </dependencies>
 </dependencyManagement>                                                                     In my main pom i have this but still get the exception sometimes

Comment: is this your complete pom.xml?paste complete pom.xml and what about client jersy client jar?

Comment: check your lib folder and verified it if it contains duplicate jor for the same.

Comment: It`s very strange.  I ran mvn dependency:tree found that jsr311-api was coming from com.sun.jersey and i removed it but still no sucess...

Comment: which version of maven you are using.could you please post your complete pom.xml?